# Усыновление и удочерение

Tags: грамотная-речь

С точки зрения русского языка все понятно: усыновляют мальчика, а удочеряют девочку.
Но интересно было бы узнать: слово "удочерение" - это, скажем так, разговорная форма или официальная и юридически признанная?
Либо все-таки тут ситуация, как с медбратом - как нам объясняли врачи в университете, в документе пишется "медсестра" вне зависимости от пола, а "медбрат" (кстати, Ворд это слово подчеркивает как ошибку) - это разговорный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

удочерять
значения слова удочерять в толковых словарях русского языка:
Ефремова Т.Ф. Толковый словарь русского языка.

удочерять
несов. перех.
1) Принимать на себя родительские права и обязанности по отношению к ребенку 
женского пола.
2) Наделять собственного внебрачного ребенка женского пола правами рожденного в 
браке.